# open URL link inside webview in mobile browser in Titanium Appcelerator

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I have a webview with HTML contents. And I have few links in that HTML content. when i clicked the link,corresponding webpage opens within my application. Can i open the webpage in mobile browser when i clicked a particular link?

I have tried using target="_blank" property within anchor tag,which doesn't works.
and also i have used "openURL" webview property, but fireEvent is not working properly.

my main js file;

```
var mywebview = Ti.UI.createWebview({
height : 'auto',
width : '100%',
html : '<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><a href="#" target="_blank" onclick="Ti.App.fireEvent("openLink", {linkUrl: "http://www.w3schools.com"});">Visit W3Schools.com!</a><br><a href="#" onclick="Ti.App.fireEvent("openLink", {linkUrl: "http://google.com"});">Visit Google.com!</a></body></html>',
)};
```

In app.js;

```
Ti.App.addEventListener("openLink", function(e){
    alert(e.linkUrl);
    Ti.Platform.openURL(e.linkUrl);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ti.App.fireEvent works for me in this form:

```
<a href="#" onclick=" Titanium.App.fireEvent('ynOpenURL', {url:'http://youatnotes.com'}); return false;">youatnotes.com</a>
```

and in app.js:

```
Ti.App.addEventListener('ynOpenURL', function(e) {
        Ti.Platform.openURL(e.url);
    });
```

You could the URL of the webview in the event in order to open the link inside the WebView.

Comment: I have used intent now. OpenURL seems to have some flaw in Titanium 3.1.3. Intent would be fine to open PDF files.

Comment: I tried above code it wokring when am loading local html in webview.
But it is not working when am loading remote url(website).
Steps:
Added Titanium.App.fireEvent code in both local html and remote url(website).
Added respective listerner in my titanium controller (.js file having webview - one .js for local html and another .js for remote url).
When I click on anchor tag of local html -> respective fireEvent and listerner working.
When I click on anchor tag of remote url -> respective fireEvent and listerner not working.